# Ruby on Rails on Windows 'SQLite' installing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite3-ruby

[image][image: error on windows installing sqlites]
I am facing this problem any one can help me. Ruby version 2.0.0 and rails version 4.2.1.
And run this Command also.
'gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby -- --with-sqlite3-include=c:/sqlite/include --with-sqlite3-lib=c:/sqlite/lib'.

Answer (score -1):

Developing Ruby in Windows will create many problems, as many gems won't even work. I'd suggest rethinking OS choice.

In your case it seem like you haven't installed SQLite (the app, not the gem). You can find it here: https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: mkmf.log "gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -Ic:/sqlite/include -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby200/lib -Lc:/sqlite/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby200  -lshell32 -lws2_32"